# How to split a list and into a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

If i have a list

```
lst = ['a', 'k', 'b', 'c', 'k', 'd', 'e', 'g']
```

and I want to split into new list without 'k', and turn it into a tuple. So I get

```
(['a'],['b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'g'])
```

I am thinking about first splitting them into different list by using a for loop.

```
new_lst = []
for element in lst:
    if element != 'k':
        new_ist.append(element)
```

This does remove all the 'k' but they are all together. I do not know how to split them into different list. To turn a list into a tuple I would need to make a list inside a list

```
a = [['a'],['b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'g']]
tuple(a) == (['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'g'])
True
```

So the question would be how to split the list into a list with sublist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are close. You can append to another list called `sublist` and if you find a `k` append `sublist` to `new_list`:

```
lst = ['a', 'k', 'b', 'c', 'k', 'd', 'e', 'g']

new_lst = []
sublist = []
for element in lst:
    if element != 'k':
        sublist.append(element)
    else:
        new_lst.append(sublist)
        sublist = []

if sublist: # add the last sublist
    new_lst.append(sublist)

result = tuple(new_lst) 
print(result)
# (['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'g'])
```

---

If you're feeling adventurous, you can also use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). The idea is to group elements as "k" or "non-k" and use `groupby` on that property:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = ['a', 'k', 'b', 'c', 'k', 'd', 'e', 'g']
result = tuple(list(gp) for is_k, gp in groupby(lst, "k".__eq__) if not is_k)

print(result)
# (['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'g'])
```

*Thanks @YakymPirozhenko for the simpler generator expression*

Answer (score 3):

```
tuple(list(i) for i in ''.join(lst).split('k'))
```

Output:

```
(['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'g'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
smallerlist = [l.split(',') for l in ','.join(lst).split('k')]
print(smallerlist)
```

Outputs

```
[['a', ''], ['', 'b', 'c', ''], ['', 'd', 'e', 'g']]
```

Then you could check if each sub lists contain ''

```
smallerlist = [' '.join(l).split() for l in smallerlist]
print(smallerlist)
```

Outputs

```
[['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'g']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach, using `re.split` from the `re` module, and `map`:

```
import re

lst = ['a', 'k', 'b', 'c', 'k', 'd', 'e', 'g']

tuple(map(list, re.split('k',''.join(lst))))

(['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'g'])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about slicing, without appending and joining .

```
def isplit_list(lst, v):
    while True:
        try:
            end = lst.index(v)
        except ValueError:
            break

        yield lst[:end]
        lst = lst[end+1:]

    if len(lst):
        yield lst


lst = ['a', 'k', 'b', 'c', 'k', 'd', 'e', 'g', 'k']

results = tuple(isplit_list(lst, 'k'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, works and doesn't need any imports!

```
>>> l = ['a', 'k', 'b', 'c', 'k', 'd', 'e', 'g']
>>> t = []
>>> for s in ''.join(l).split('k'):
...     t.append(list(s))
...
>>> t
[['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'g']]
>>> t = tuple(t)
>>> t
(['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'g'])
```

Why don't you make a method which will take a list as an argument and return a tuple like so.

```
>>> def list_to_tuple(l):
...     t = []
...     for s in l:
...             t.append(list(s))
...     return tuple(t)
...
>>> l = ['a', 'k', 'b', 'c', 'k', 'd', 'e', 'g']
>>> l = ''.join(l).split('k')
>>> l = list_to_tuple(l)
>>> l
(['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'g'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using itertools

```
import more_itertools

lst = ['a', 'k', 'b', 'c', 'k', 'd', 'e', 'g']

print(tuple(more_itertools.split_at(lst, lambda x: x == 'k')))
```

gives

```
(['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'g'])
```